# browser.executeScript gives errors (Angularjs,protractor,unittesting)

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, protractor

in my test i have a piece of code that the browser.executeScript executes but there are some errors with it that i cant fix

this is the browser.executeScript code :

```
browser.executeScript('var allcookies = document.cookie;
cookiearray = allcookies.split(";");
for (var i = 0; i < cookiearray.length; i++)
{
    name = cookiearray[i].split("=")[0];
    value = cookiearray[i].split("=")[1];
    console.log("Key is : " + name + " and Value is : " + value);
}
sidValue = value;
console.log(value);
console.log(sidValue);
receiptNumber = $scope.row.nr;
window.location.href("https://www.mysite.nl/info?sid=" + sidValue + "&filter={nr:" + receiptNumber + "}");');
```

i have two problems:

1. $scope.row.nr ,it says that $scope is not defined
2. on my window.location.href it saysProperty 'href' of object [object Location] is not a function (when i remove href it says the same only about location).

Does anybody knows how to fix this?

Comment: 2. is solved with : window.location="https://www.mysite.nl/info?sid="+ sidValue +"&filter={nr:"+ receiptNumber + "}";

Answer (score 3):

`executeScript` runs in the global context where `$scope` is not defined by angular. If you go to your web console and enter `$scope` you can replicate it.

You would need to query the elements scope property like so 

`angular.element( document.querySelectorAll('.your-element')[0] ).scope()`

Then it looks like @Basman01 has an answer for your second issue.